# how to parse JSON to and from c# without external libraries or reference

Tags: c#, json, parsing, format

I am currently creating a string extension namespace for c# and I want part of it to be able to parse to/from JSON. The option of `json.net` is not valid as I don't want any third-party libraries/namespaces going on. (as I cannot use other namespaces to create a namespace to help others, this would be absurd) I also don't want to use `javascriptserializer` as in order to use it a reference to `System.Web.Script.Serialization` must be and I don't want my namespaces' users to have to add a reference so that this question: [Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp) won't help me. I need the function to match any `object`. how can it be done?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

// after you got json as string

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: "The option of json.net is not valid as I don't want any third-party libraries/namespaces going on"